# Drools/ Kogito Dynamic runtime flow/ process

Tags: drools, jbpm, drools-flow, dmn, kogito

I'm new to drools (I can consider Kogito as well) we have a requirements where the rules with orders are stored in a decision table and it should be executed based on the order given by the users the rules order could change at anytime. Please keep in mind that the response(output) from any rules is the input for the next one. is there anyway to achieve this?

example:

| Rules | rank |
| --- | --- |
| rule 1 | 1 |
| rule 2 | 2 |

order might change to:

| Rules | rank |
| --- | --- |
| rule 1 | 2 |
| rule 2 | 1 |

Comment: Sure, it's possible.

Comment: Hi @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas, do you have any sample/ explanation how to achieve this?

Comment: No because that's off topic here. But if you try to solve the problem yourself and run into specific issues we can help you with that.